# String similarity comparison in python

Tags: python, list, string-comparison, similarity

I am trying to write a program that compares a list of scrambled names, to a big list of regular names, character by character.

For example let's say one of the names in the scrambled list is `B@B St@r#` and I'm trying to compare that name to the list of regular names and see how many characters it has in common with or if its a perfect match with one of the names of the regular list.

My code so far is this:

```
for ch in list2:    ##list 2 has the decrypted names
    parts = ch.split()
    decryptedfirst_names.append(parts[0]) ##Im trying to compare first names for now
    for ch in list1:  ##list1 is a big list of regular names
        part = ch.split()
        first_names.append(part[0])

matching = []
for ch in first_names:
    if ch in decryptedfirst_names and ch not in matching:
        matching.append(ch)
print(matching)
```

Then this code will just print the name of the match.

I need help trying to calculate the exact number of characters that match by position, that way I can put it in a percentage like 80% match and so on and if possible, something a beginner can program.

Comment: The Google made [diff-match-patch package](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) has a lot of what you're already looking for.  You'll probably be most interested in`diff`

Comment: I appreciate it, Im just looking for something I can do and understand a bit more.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your problem could be solved by the levenshtein distance between two words. It gives you a similarity metric for two strings.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance):

> The Levenshtein distance is a string metric for measuring the
>   difference between two sequences. Informally, the Levenshtein distance
>   between two words is the minimum number of single-character edits
>   (i.e. insertions, deletions or substitutions) required to change one
>   word into the other.

You can find a python implementation of the levenshtein distance on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/)

```
pip install python-levenshtein
```